# Is there a C++ equivalent (or equivalent technique) of Perl's __DATA__ segment?

Tags: c++, perl, data-segment

is anyone aware of a C++ equivalent of Perl's `__DATA__` segment? For anyone not familiar with Perl, the `__DATA__` segment is an (optional) annotation towards the end of a Perl file; whatever comes after is considered the content of a (virtual) file which can be accessed (read, written) by Perl through the DATA file handle. I'm looking for something similar to use in a C++ program (don't ask, don't tell).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There’s nothing like that in general.

However, the Linux ELF binary format allows the [inclusion of data files via the GNU tool `objcopy`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/embedding-file-executable-aka-hello-world-version-5967).

On Windows you can use [resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and assign the linker to include those in the executable.

OS X conventionally uses [application bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle) to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Ok, I'll just stick with resource files side by side with executables.